# How can one direct traffic through tor when using terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu with tor browser and would like to direct all traffic through tor, most specifically redirecting ALL traffic from terminal through tor?

Comment: It might be worth considering torify. Just type “torify [command]”. It doesn’t direct all terminal traffic just whatever program you torified but it’s an option worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at tails distribution. It is Debian based and it is doing exactly that you want. If you want to redirect all network traffic through tor OpnSense is doing that after you enable and setup tor plugin.